# How hunter.io works (find all email address from domain URL)?

Tags: web-scraping

I'm working on a tool to find all emails address from a domain name, as snov.io/hunter.io does.

Do you have any idea about how to find all email address from the domain, with the name, last name, social profile URL, and the source of the mail (see image for reference)?

[image: Image refrence]

I was thinking to use anyleads API but seems that it cannot be implemented in software.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is working like web scraping and crawling. when you enter the domain name it will read the web page text and find email format and show that. This will be first fact and second is it will be find email from search engine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31569058)